# Printing characters in a matrix as a string

Tags: python, performance

I need to solve this problem in Python 3 (within 3 sec):

> `A` is a given (NxM) rectangle, filled with characters "a" to "z".
>   Start from `A[1][1]` to `A[N][M]` collect all character which is only
>   one in its row and column, print them as a string.
>
> Input:
>
> \$N\$, \$M\$ in first line (number of row and column \$1 \le N\$, \$M \le
> > 1000\$). Next, \$N\$ lines contain exactly \$M\$ characters.
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> A single string
> ```
>
> Sample input 1:
>
> ```
> 1 9
> arigatodl
> ```
>
> Sample output 1:
>
> ```
> rigtodl
> ```
>
> Sample input 2:
>
> ```
> 5 6
> cabboa
> kiltik
> rdetra
> kelrek
> dmcdnc
> ```
>
> Sample output 2:
>
> ```
> codermn
> ```

This is still not fast enough when \$N\$, \$M\$ = 1000. I'd like suggestions on improving the speed, or any other ways to solve the given problem, as long as the solution is in Python 3 and is faster than mine.

```py
from operator import itemgetter
Words,Chars,answer=[],"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",""
N,M=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
for _ in range(N):
    Words.append(input())
                                    # got the inputs
for row,word in enumerate(Words):   # going through each words
    Doubts=[]                       # collect chars only one in its row.
    for char in Chars:
            if (word.count(char)==1):
                    Doubts.append((char,word.index(char)))
    for case in sorted(Doubts,key=itemgetter(1)):   #sorting by index
            doubtless=True                  #checking whether 1 in its column or not.
            for i in range(N):
                    if (Words[i][case[1]]==case[0] and i!=row):
                            doubtless=False
                            break
            if (doubtless):
                    answer+=case[0] #if char is one in its row and column, adds to answer.
print (answer)
```

Comment: Not an observation about optimization, but why aren't you using [PEP8 guidelines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to write your code? It's not a dealbreaker by any means, but 1) Why don't you have spaces between operators and 2) Capital/CamelCase is usually reserved for class definitions.

Comment: Thanks, but this time I wasn't wondering about how it looks. I was worrying about how it works :)

Comment: For info, this has been [cross-posted at StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969733/optimisations-for-this-code-in-python-3).

Comment: You didn't have to delete it, just **declare** the cross-posting. Then people can use the hyperlink to determine whether you still need assistance. It's about being considerate of other people's time, and as I said on the other thread, this has been part of netiquette for thirty years or so.

Comment: I'll take a look at it a bit more in depth, but it appears that you're iterating over the elements in the matrix more times then necessary. You *should* be able to write an algorithm that does at most `N * M * k_nm` checks, where k is the number of unique letters in each row/column. (by unique I mean a member of the set of letters, I don't mean that they don't repeat in the sequence)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create a 1000x1000 testcase and measure the performance before the optimization process. Please use the following test generator:

```
import os
import random

f = open('1000x1000.in','w')
f.write('1000 1000\n')
ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for _ in range(1000):
       f.write(''.join([ALPHABET[random.randint(0, len(ALPHABET)-1)] for _ in range(1000)]) + '\n')
f.close()
```

After that just run it and measure the performance of your application. I got about **47 ms** on my pretty old C2D E7200.

Answer (score 1):

You could improve part of your loop.

```
Doubts=[]                     
for char in Chars:
        if (word.count(char)==1):
                Doubts.append((char,word.index(char)))
```

Can be done with list-comprehension.

```
    Doubts = [(char, word.index(char)) for char in Chars if word.count(char) == 1]
```